Do not dismiss keyboard when DropdownMenu is opened
In my Jetpack Compose app, it seems that any time I open a popup such as DropdownMenu while I'm typing something, the keyboard will disappear. Perhaps this happens because the TextField loses focus? I can't find why this happens.
For my use case this is very jarring and I would like the IME to remain up while the DropdownMenu is opened. Is this possible to achieve? It seems to be the default behavior for non-Compose apps. See attached animations for comparison.



If you set properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false) opening DropDownMenu won't dismiss keyboard.
But when setting focusable to false clicking another item will invoke click action if available. By default DropDownMenu handles this click and consume but with false it doesn't.
If you also need to prevent this you can have custom click on parent or root Composable by change propagation direction with PointerEventPass.Initial and consume event.
